# In Ruby on Rails, if we generated a model "Animal", and now want to have "Dog", how should we do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, single-table-inheritance, rails-models

say, if we generated a model

```
rails generate model animal name:string birthday:date
```

and now we want to create other model to inherit from it (such as Dog and Cat), should we use `rails generate model` again or just add the files ourselves?  How do we specify Dog should inherit from Animal if we use `rails generate model`?

I think if we use `rails generate model` instead of adding the model files ourselves, there will be unit test files and fixture files created for us as well.  A migration file is also added, except if it is using MongoDB, then there will be no migration file.

Answer (score 6):

If the `Dog`, `Cat` and other subclasses you are planning are not going to diverge away from `Animal` model, you can [STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) pattern here.

To do that, add a `String` column to `Animal`. And then you can have:

```
class Dog < Animal
end

class Cat < Animal
end

>> scooby = Dog.create(:name => 'Scooby', :date => scoobys_birthdate)
=> #<Dog id: 42, date: "YYYY-MM-DD", type: "Dog">
```

To generate model `Dog`

```
$ script/generate model Dog --skip-migration
```

And then change (usually `app/models/dog.rb`):

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
```

to

```
class Dog < Animal
```

Comment: i see... how about if there is additional property with this class, such as `fur_color:string`?  how does it affect the `generate` and the tables?

Comment: If you add a new column, say `fur_color` as you say, it'll be available for all the subclasses. It may not make sense always, for eg. you have `class Snake < Animal`, now snakes do not have furs. But column would still exist. But if you only have furred animals in your system then it makes perfect sense.
This is what I meant by diverging from the original `Animal` model. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can define the superclass when generating a model by specifying a `--parent` flag. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14569424) post. It will not generate any migrations either, from what I have observed.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't specify a superclass when generating a model. However, generators are only a stepping stone to creating your classes. You can generate the model class as normal and simply change the superclass in the generated model file. There are no other places that the inheritance relationship has to be specified for the generated files to work (the fixtures and unit tests for example don't specify super- or subclasses).

So:

```
script/generate model Dog
```

Then change:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
```

to:

```
class Dog < Animal
```

If you want to generate a model that will inherit from Animal using single table inheritance then you may want to specify --skip-migrations on the script/generate call (though you may want a migration to add e.g. dog-specific columns to the animals table and you will need to add a `type` column of type string to the animals table).

Comment: This needs a String column named `type` to be present in `Animal`.