# What is the Rails (>=3.1) generator syntax for creating a subclass model / scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, subclass

What is the command line syntax for generating a subclass model or scaffold in Rails?

`rails g model Mysubclass my_field:string ....`

How do I specify the parent class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use "--parent=ParentClass".

Example:

1) Create a parent class "User".

> rails g scaffold User login:string

2) Create a child class "Teacher".

> rails g scaffold Teacher url:string --parent=User

But remember: you still need to create migrations(adding columns in datatables) and change views(adding fields in forms).

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect for single table inheritance (STI).

Comment: (You can find the mention of using `--parent` by running `rails generate model --help`)

Answer (score 1):

Just as Ruby syntax:

```
rails g model Parent::Children
```

Comment: This creates a model in a subdirectory (and submodule), not a subclass

Comment: This is not correct. This will create a module and not a subclass!